# Automatic Pivot Table in VBA - Error invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have the following code.  When it gets to the ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches .. i get the invalid procedure call or argument.  I built this using the Macro Recorder.  Not sure how to fix it.
Thanks for the help.

```
Sub PivotTable()
  Sheets("YTD Sr Director").Select
  Range("A3").Select
  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "YTD Detail!R1C1:R1048576C19", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
     CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="YTD Sr Director!R3C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
  Sheets("YTD Sr Director").Select
  Cells(3, 1).Select
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Pay Amount")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
  End With
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("# of Drivers"), "Count of # of Drivers", xlCount
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Safety Bonus Paid"), "Count of Safety Bonus Paid",_ 
    xlCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enclose your sheet name with pair of single quote:
From `"YTD Detail!R1C1:R1048576C19"`
to `"'YTD Detail'!R1C1:R1048576C19"`

in the SourceData and TableDestination arguments.

For more info, read here:
http://www.ugrowit.net/0815-excel-pivot-error-while-recording-a-macro-to-create-pivot-table-automatically/